# When do you need to inform the UKVI of a change in circumstances?

Tags: visas, uk

Edit: This question is for visit visas whilst the applicant is outside the UK.

Let's suppose someone has a long term 2, 5 or 10 year visa. Under what circumstances is he/she obliged to tell the UKVI? Does he need to inform the UKVI if:

1. There is a change in financial circumstances? How big of a change must it be?
2. If there is a new criminal conviction that would normally not be general grounds for refusal?
3. If the applicant has been refused a visa for another country, removed or refused entry?
4. Marriage? Birth of a child? Death of a family member?
5. Sex change?

The rules say

> 321A. The following grounds for the cancellation of a person’s leave to enter or remain which is in force on his arrival in, or whilst he is outside, the United Kingdom apply;
>
> (1) there has been such a change in the circumstances of that person’s case since the leave was given, that it should be cancelled; or

The rules don't define what "such a change in the circumstances" is.

Comment: https://gayotfow.wordpress.com/2018/03/22/removal-based-upon-change-of-circumstances-paragraph-321/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [GOV.UK website](https://www.gov.uk/change-circumstances-visa-brp/youre-outside-the-uk):

> Contact the visa application centre where you applied if you’re outside the UK and there’s a change to your:
>
> •reason for going to the UK
>
> •address
>
> •personal details, for example your name, because you got married
>
> You may need to make another visa application at your local visa application centre.

Which means, as long as you're a genuine visitor, you only need to declare changes of address or personal details.

That said, regarding finances, it is your responsibility to ensure you can support yourself during a visit without resorting to employment or public funds, and that you can prove it on request at the border. If you can't, and they catch you on it, your visa will be cancelled.

Several of the other things you mentioned would have to be reported if you were a UK resident, but not if you're a visitor.

Comment: I believe that page is referring to residency visas, not short term visas.

Comment: @JonathanReez Called the UKVI (yes, I actually bothered wasting the money) - the "outside the UK" section applies to visitors as well.

Comment: I've also noticed its posted under the "Manage your application" section. Are you sure it is about issued visas, rather than visas that are still in processing?

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes, it says "if you have a visa or BRP", which implies it applies to current visa holders as well. It's also what the UKVI told me

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the specific visa but for example for a [Tier 1, 2, 4 or 5](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/notification-of-change-of-circumstances-form-mcc) visa a change of circumstances is defined as:

> - personal details
> - criminal convictions
> - contact details
> - representative’s details
> - dependants’ details
> - any other information you think UKVI should know

For a [biometric residence permit](https://www.gov.uk/change-circumstances-visa-brp) (BRP) a change of circumstances is defined as:

> - address
> - name, for example if you’ve got married
> - nationality
> - facial appearance
> - date of birth, for example if it was wrong
> - gender
> - you get a criminal conviction
> - you separate from your partner
> - any of your children stop living permanently with you

Comment: I get that. My question is about visit visas whilst outside the UK. Edited for clarity.